# Optgroup issue in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Actually I have main categories under main categories I have list of products. For first main category I have subcategory and subcategory related products. whichever main category is not having subcategories I am splitting array with comma separator and appending that products to select dropdown. But if main category is having subcategory means I need to do optgroup with options. In optgroup subcatname and related products.
For example, subcatname1=> p1,p2,p3, subcatname2=> p1,p2,p3.
How we can resolve this please help somebody.

Below is HTML,

```
<select name="category" id="category" /> 
   <option selected ="selected">Select category</option>

   <?php foreach($decode as $key => $value) { ?>

          <option value="<?php echo $value['category_id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option>


          <?php } ?>

 </select>
<select name="category12" class="category12" /></select>
```

Below is Jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#category').change(function(){
        var category_id=$('#category').val();
          $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          url: 'data_product.php?category_id='+category_id,
          success: function(data) {
          var products = data.split(",");
          state_html = '';
          state_html = '<option>Please Select product</option>'
          $.each(products, function (index, productName) {
                 state_html += "<option value='"+productName+"'>"+productName+"</option>";

                 //var gain=
                });
                $('.category12').html(state_html);
            },
        $.each(data, function (index, sub_cat_name) {
                 state_html += "<optgroup label='"+sub_cat_name+"'>"+sub_cat_name+"
                    <option value="+products_name+">"+products_name+"</option>
                 </optgroup>";

                 //var gain=
                });
                $('.category12').html(state_html);
            },

        });
    })
});
```

Comment: can you give me sample array

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate only once for your `data` and split the `productnames` from it.

Try the below code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#category').change(function() {
    var category_id = this.value; // use simply this.value here
    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: 'data_product.php?category_id=' + category_id,
      dataType:'json',
      success: function(data) {
        state_html = '<option>Please Select product</option>'
        $.each(data, function(sub_cat_name, product) {
          // split all products here
          var products = product.split(",");
          make optgroup from sub_cat_name key
          state_html += "<optgroup label='" + sub_cat_name + "'>" + sub_cat_name;
          // loop for all product options
          for (var i = , l = products.length; i < l; i++) {
            state_html += "<option value='" + products[i] + "'>" + products[i] + "</option>";
          }
          state_html += "</optgroup>"; // close optgroup here
        });
        // finally append all options
        $('.category12').html(state_html);
      }
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: You need to add `dataType:'json',` or use `$.parseJSON` see my updated answer.